# C# DLL depends on another dll

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, dll

I'm making a project with Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 and C#. With this project I want to generate a .dll.

In my project I have an external reference  to `itextsharp.dll` and this give me an error when I try to use `myproject.dll` on another computer it gives me an error:

> Can't load file or assembly itextsharp...

So, anyone knows how can I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just copy itextsharp.dll to the same folder as myproject.dll

Also this can be automated by setting "Local Copy" property of  to "true". So after each rebuild Visual Studio will automatically copy the .dll-file for you near to all compiled dll/exe files of current project..

Comment: The propierty copy local of the reference `itextsharp.dll` was already true. Everytime I build my project it build `myproject.dll` and `itextsharp.dll`.

Should the reference to this dll be in the same path where the build operation build it?

Comment: @Sharekhan, just change this property to "true" - Visual Studio will make all work for you.

If they are not installed globally on another computer - yes they must be there. This setting property make direct instruction for Visual Studio to copy referenced library

Comment: @Sharekhan, *setting this property

Comment: Yes, I saw that setting this propierty to true make VS copy the library to the output path but last time didn't work. I think because the reference to the library wasn't this path. It was another. I will try if it works now. Thanks! @rufanov

Answer (score 0):

Edit the web.config file to remove the reference, which is not required for normal operation:

1 - Open the web.config/app.config file in the root of your site

2 - Find the following line and comment it ():xxxxx-is your assembly name.

```
<add assembly="xxxxx", Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>3 - Save and close the web.config file and try again
```

Ref Link : http://manual.aspdotnetstorefront.com/p-1118-could-not-load-file-or-assembly-microsoftwebservices3-version3000-cultureneutral-publickeytoken31bf3856ad364e35.aspx

UPDATE :

The above is not working then you need to refer the itextsharp.dll in new project as well.The reason is.

itextsharp.dll--> level 0 (not depending on other dlls)
Myprojet.dll  --> level 1 (depending on itextsharp.dll)
consuming App --> level 2 (depending on level 1 , level 2)

After build the consuming app you have to get the level 0,level 1 dlls in bin folders.So you have to add itextSharp.dll as a reference.

Answer (score 0):

If you add a dll in your project, that is not a Microsoft build in .dll, you must copy/paste this .dll with you Application. They must be together, because this .dll is searched from your Application in the current directory where the Application is.

Comment: Or just change one property of this referenced library in the project window - set "Local Copy" to "true". And after each rebuild Visual Studio will automatically copy the .dll-file for you..